# Printing rectangles using graphics java

Tags: java, graphics, integer

I am trying to draw multiple rectangles using separate integer values.

```
    BufferedImage rectImage = bimage.myBImage;
    BufferedImage pointImage = bimage.myBImage;
    Graphics g = rectImage.createGraphics();
    Graphics h = pointImage.createGraphics();
    Color rectangle = Color.CYAN;
    g.setColor(rectangle);
    int alon = -118;
    int alat = 34;
    int x = (int) Math.round((alon-UL_Lon)/dXLon);
    int y = (int) Math.round((UL_Lat-alat)/dYLat);
    g.drawRect(x - 5, y - 5, 10, 10);
    Color point = Color.BLUE;
    h.setColor(point);
    h.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
```

I have multiple values for alon and alat that I would like to be able to input without having to rewrite the code over and over again.

How should I go about doing something like this?

Comment: what do you mean multiple values? are the values a sequence? or just random?

Comment: Thought of a for-loop?

Comment: BTW `rectImage` and `pointImage` are effectivelly the same object.

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty vague and not worded very well. I'm presuming from what I've gathered you want to render multiple rectangles at different places with different sizes. You should first define how many rectangles you want:

```
int numberOfRectangles = 5;
```

Then you should create an array that can hold the number of rectangles you defined:

```
Rectangle rectangles[] = new Rectangle[numberOfRectangles];
```

Now, you must define the rectangles:

```
rectangles[0] = new Rectangle(7, 64, 32, 32);
rectangles[1] = new Rectangle(64, 18, 4, 32);
```

You appear to also want to set colors? So you can do that by making an array:

```
Color rectangleColors[] = new Color[numberOfRectangles];
```

Then also defining them:

```
rectangleColors[0] = new Color(255, 48, 128);
rectangleColors[1] = Color.GREEN;
```

Because of the system you don't have to define all the rectangles at once. Now, you must cycle through the rectangles array and render each of the defined rectangles using the render method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRectangles; i++)
{
    g.setColor(rectangleColors[i]);
    g.fillRect(rectangles[i].getX(), rectangles[i].getY(), rectangles[i].getWidth(), rectangles[i].getHeight());
}
```

This **should** work, though I haven't tested it out in Java.

Comment: If, this is the correct comment then the author should accept it. So far the author doesn't appear to have viewed his question or accepted any answers.

Answer (score 0):

If the values that you want to give your Rectangles completely random, then you'll have to copy-paste the code and change the values. However, if the values are a sequence (like you want to create 20 rectangle adjacent to each other for instance) You can use a `for` [loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

```
for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
          int x = (int) Math.round((alon-UL_Lon + i)/dXLon);
          int y = (int) Math.round((UL_Lat-alat + i)/dYLat);
          g.drawRect(x - 5, y - 5, 10, 10);
     }
```

Like this